# Synonyms for prepopulated/prefilled?

Tags: synonyms

What are some synonyms for prefilled or prepoluated?
I've looked up many synonym resources but being pre-populate and pre-fill compound words I didn't get anything useful out of them.

**Use case:** I need to communicate to a client that at a specific web page they can find a prefilled payment form, but I don't want to use the word *prefilled* because it has been used before, so I would like to avoid repeating it.

Comment: We need to know how you want to use the word, and why prefilled and prepopulated aren't doing the trick.

Comment: Added context information.

Comment: Thanks, can you please remove the on-hold status now?

Comment: I voted to reopen already.  I think at this point you need two more reopen votes.  You could post the request at ELU Meta, I think.

Comment: This is too much burden on the user side, given I also changed the question to follow the rules. I did my part. Maybe it would be fair if you could mention the other  moderators' names in another comment of yours to attract back their attention? Thanks.

Comment: There is something you yourself can do about this if you want to speed it up.  You can pose a question on ELU Meta, along the lines of "Please re-open my edited question."

Comment: *At (specific web page), you can find a payment form with most of the necessary information pre-entered.*  Or: with most of the necessary information already entered for you.

Answer (score 1):

*Prefilling* or *prepopulating* a value applies almost exclusively to computer input and such a value is called the *default* (value).

ODO:

> **[default](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/default)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **2** [in singular] A preselected option adopted by a computer program or other mechanism when no alternative is specified by the user or
>   programmer:
>
> ‘the default is fifty lines’
>
> [as modifier] ‘default settings’